# How do I stop a monster from dropping a quest item once the related quest is finished?

Tags: rpg-maker-mv

I'm trying to make a quest. When the quest is activated (switch is on), monsters should drop a certain quest item. After the quest is finished (switch is off), those monsters should stop dropping the quest item. How can I do this?

Comment: have you by chance seen this plugin? http://www.yanfly.moe/wiki/Quest_Journal_System_(YEP) . It is free at the time of this comment and works great for making quest options in RPG Maker MV. PS. I don't work for them and am not trying to advertise for them, just to point you in the direction of a tool to help you with your purpose. -Not posted as an answer because it doesn't directly address your question and uses a 3rd party plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what your looking for. Go to "Troops" Tab in "database" and pick the troop
you want to use and look in the conditions window and select "conditional branch".From the 
selections click "switch" type or choose a desired switch and click ok, in this case we
are naming our switch "quest item potions". Then click inside the conditional branch and select "change items" and choose a potion. Make sure increase is checked and not decrease or else it will take away a potion. so now if you choose to turn on (switch)"quest item potions" it'll give you a potion. BUT WE ARE FORGETTING SOMETHING STILL! Make sure to change the conditions window to the desired one in this case I picked "turn end".
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Also don't forget after all this is done you still need to turn the switch "ON" for it to work. a nice example would be to make an "Event" have it tell you to hunt some bats and bring them a "potion" and then have that "Event" turn on the "Switch" "quest item potions" and then when you give the potion to the "Event" have the "event" turn the "Switch" back off.

Answer (score 0):

If you have something like a loot table system where you can change the chance of the item appearing, you could set it to 0% to make sure it doesn't show up. 
Other options are

- The quest adding the item to the loot table while the quest is active
  and removing it when it's inactive.
- Having a locked state on your item, so it means that it cannot spawn.

And there are probably a lot more ways to go about this problem. Look at your architecture and see what's the best for your game. I would go for the second option, but it all depends on what kind of architecture you have for your game.

Comment: This answer would be better if it included some details about how to apply this advice in the specific framework of RPG Maker MV

Comment: Yeah, this answer sounds very generic. When i sat down and generalized my RPG's framework in Unity, some of these kind of things would work with it.